# What is the property that allow the transformation $\frac{16a^3}{8ac}=\frac{16}8\cdot\frac{a^3}a\cdot\frac1c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

In a monomial division like this:
$$\frac{16a^3}{8ac}=\frac{16}8\cdot\frac{a^3}a\cdot\frac1c$$
Why I can do this $\dfrac1c$? Where this 1 come from?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that $\frac1c$ isn't supposed to be there. Maybe you copied down the problem down incorrectly?

Comment: Now is correct.

Comment: Hint: $16\cdot a^3=16\cdot a^3\cdot1$. (Anything times $1$ is itself...)

Comment: (P.S. I suggested an edit so that the equation should now read this:)$$\frac{16a^3}{8ac}=\frac{16}8\cdot\frac{a^3}a\cdot\frac1c$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand it now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would say that it's because $c^0=1$ hence, you've got :
$$\frac{16a^3}{8ac}=\frac{16a^3c^0}{8ac} =\frac{16}{8}\cdot\frac{a^3}{a}\cdot\frac{c^0}{c} =\frac{16}{8}\cdot\frac{a^3}{a}\cdot\frac{1}{c}$$

Comment: Whhaaat? This isn't a *reason*; just a convenient fact to make sense of the distribution.

Comment: Well, this convention is the reason why you can write it that way and consider it a monomial, isn't it? It's true that if we're talking about commutative algebra, then it's no good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because 1 is the unity for multiplication/division.

(And I think there is a typo in the question)